# Prepare a json object from unmarshaled data

Tags: json, go, encoding-json-go

I have json data like this:

```
json: {"opt1":200,"opt3":"1","opt4":"13","opt5":null,"products":[{"product_id":1,"price":100,"variant_id":100},{"product_id":1,"price":100,"variant_id":null}]}
```

I have structured it using

```
type Products struct {
    Product_id int
    Price json.Number
    Variant_id int
}


type Pdata struct {
    Products []Products `json:"products"`
}
```

Then I use unmarshal

```
jsonb := []byte(jsonVal)
    var data Pdata
    err := json.Unmarshal(jsonb, &data)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

And get output like

```
{[{1 100 100} {2 100 0}]}
```

Now I need to convert that data into a json object like this

```
{"purchased_products": [{"product_id": 1,"price": 1200,"variation_id": 100},{"product_id": 2,"price": 100,"variation_id": null}]}
```

After that, I need to assign it to "json"

```
var d = map[string]string{
    "json":        jsonVal,
    "created_at":  time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
    "updated_at":  time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this example, see if it helps. https://play.golang.org/p/9MX-hOHkOno

Comment: @Animesh that playground doesn't account for the `"variant_id":null` in your JSON output. Not sure if that's actually a requirement or not. Please see mine or mkopriva's answers

Comment: @blackgreen my requirement is ok with that output.

Comment: @Animesh then you should clarify that in your question because valid answers are different based on that single detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a type (eg : PurchasedProducts) as below.

```
type PurchasedProducts struct {
    Products []Products `json:"purchased_products"`
}
```

And init a PurchasedProducts type variable and assign your unmarshaled products to Purchased products as below.

```
    pProducts := PurchasedProducts{Products: data.Products}
    jsonByte, err := json.Marshal(pProducts)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

And convert that `[]byte` array to a string and assign it to the map like below.

```
    var d = map[string]string{
        "json":        string(jsonByte),
        "created_at":  time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
        "updated_at":  time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
    }
```

You can run and see full code [here](https://play.golang.org/p/hRLu3PjDMss).

Answer (score 1):

For nullable fields you can use pointers, so for example if the `variant_id` json field can be an integer or a json `null`, and you want to retain that information, then you can change `Variant_id int` to `Variant_id *int`.

```golang
type Product struct {
    Product_id int         `json:"product_id"`
    Price      json.Number `json:"price"`
    Variant_id *int        `json:"variant_id"`
}
```

---

To change json field names between unmarshal and marshal you can declare a second `Products` struct with the same fields as the original but with struct tags defining the desired field names, then, if the structs are, in all other respects, equivalent you can convert between them.

```golang
type Product struct {
    Product_id int         `json:"product_id"`
    Price      json.Number `json:"price"`
    Variant_id int         `json:"variant_id"`
}

type PurchasedProduct struct {
    Product_id int         `json:"product_id"`
    Price      json.Number `json:"price"`
    Variant_id int         `json:"variation_id"` // here variant_id becomes variation_id
}
```

Then, if `p` is of type `Product`, you can simply convert it to `PurchasedProduct` like so:

```golang
pp := PurchasedProduct(p)
```

---

To offload the conversion to the marshaling process you can have the original types implement the `json.Marshaler` interface and do the conversion there.

```golang
func (p Product) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type P struct {
        Product_id int         `json:"product_id"`
        Price      json.Number `json:"price"`
        Variant_id *int        `json:"variation_id"`
    }
    return json.Marshal(P(p))
}
```

---

With the above you can do the following:

```golang
func main() {
    // unmarshal
    var pd Pdata
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &pd)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // marshal
    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(pd, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/0gnrjgUslza

Answer (score 1):

Simply define two more structs that model the second JSON object:

```
type Pdata2 struct {
    PurchasedProducts []Product2
}

type Product2 struct {
    Product_id    int
    Price         json.Number
    Variation_id  *int // pointer to int
}
```

The `Variation_id` field is an `*int` type because your required output JSON shows `"variation_id": null`. If you declare the field as simple `int`, its zero value will be marshaled to `0`.

Then initialize those structs using values from the previous ones:

```
func main() {
    data2 := Pdata2{
        PurchasedProducts: make([]Product2, len(data.Products)),
    }

    for i, p := range data.Products {
        data2.PurchasedProducts[i] = Product2{
            Product_id:   p.Product_id,
            Price:        p.Price,
            Variation_id: nullableInt(p.Variant_id),
        }
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(data2)
    if err != nil {
        // ... handle error
    }
    var d = map[string]string{
        "json": string(b),
        // ...
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
}

func nullableInt(n int) *int {
    if n == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    return &n
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/xhsmHNBjRKN

Answer (score 0):

Here you are.
Assumptions are that:

- Product is a model which could be much more complicated, thus it has dedicated structs. Thus transformation from Product to OutputProduct can be unit tested separately.
- It is one time use application, not a part of the application which exposes an API. Otherwise it should be properly separated into layers and the output should be written as a structure.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"
)

type (
    Product struct {
        ProductID int `json:"product_id"`
        VariantID int `json:"variant_id"`
        Price     json.Number
    }
    Products []Product

    OutputProduct struct {
        ProductID int `json:"product_id"`
        VariantID int `json:"variation_id"`
        Price     json.Number
    }
)

func (p Product) ToOutputProduct() OutputProduct {
    return OutputProduct{
        ProductID: p.ProductID,
        VariantID: p.VariantID,
        Price:     p.Price,
    }
}

func (p Products) ToOutputProducts() []OutputProduct {
    outputProducts := make([]OutputProduct, len(p))
    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        outputProducts[i] = p[i].ToOutputProduct()
    }
    return outputProducts
}

func main() {
    var inputJSON = `{"opt1":200,"opt3":"1","opt4":"13","opt5":null,"products":[{"product_id":1,"price":100,"variant_id":100},{"product_id":1,"price":100,"variant_id":null}]}`

    var parsedInput struct {
        Products Products
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(inputJSON), &parsedInput); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var output = map[string]interface{}{
        "json":       map[string][]OutputProduct{
            "purchased_products": parsedInput.Products.ToOutputProducts(),
        },
        "created_at": time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
        "updated_at": time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
    }
    encoder := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout)
    encoder.SetIndent(" ", "  ")
    if err := encoder.Encode(output); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the suggestions from comments:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "time"
)

type Products struct {
    Product_id int `json:"product_id"`
    Price      int `json:"price"`
    Variant_id int `json:"variant_id"`
}

type ProductData struct {
    Products []Products `json:"products"`
}

type Response struct {
    Json      json.RawMessage `json:"json"`
    CreatedAt string          `json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt string          `json:"updated_at"`
}

func main() {
    productJson := `{
        "opt1": 200,
        "opt3": "1",
        "opt4": "13",
        "opt5": null,
        "products": [
            { "product_id": 1, "price": 100, "variant_id": 100 },
            { "product_id": 1, "price": 100, "variant_id": null }
        ]
    }`

    productData := &ProductData{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(productJson), &productData)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(map[string]interface{}{"purchased_products": productData.Products})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    d := &Response{
        Json:      b,
        CreatedAt: time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
        UpdatedAt: time.Now().Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"),
    }

    out, err := json.Marshal(d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    log.Println(string(out))
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 {"json":{"purchased_products":[{"product_id":1,"price":100,"variant_id":100},{"product_id":1,"price":100,"variant_id":0}]},"created_at":"2009-11-10 23:00:00","updated_at":"2009-11-10 23:00:00"}
```